# Java skipping System.out.println while debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am debugging my java source for a web-app running on an virtual machine.

I added `System.out.println(variable)` get see it in the console, but debugger is literally skipping this line of source.

Is there a way to print the variable into console?

Comment: This may be a silly question, but did you stop the program and recompile it?

Comment: No, but i am going to do it right away. I will post back.

Comment: Please try with recompiling your code (after you have added the System.out line) from eclipse and then start debugging.

Comment: Yeah, that should take care of your issue. The problem being that the running program has no knowledge of what you added. Until you recompile that is

Comment: Recompile means I create a new .jar and replace it with the old one.?

Comment: The class with the `System.out.println` line in - is it in a jar in referenced libraries, or is it in your src directory?

Comment: It is current in the src directory. Bu my webapp already contains a similar jar but without this line. I suppose when in debugging mode we use directly the source code from src.